# Wrong number in "List of contents"

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to add the "List of Contents" section to the List of Contents itself using the code below. However, when compiling, the page associated with the List of Contents refers to the previous chapter, instead of the right one, that is: it says the list of contents is in page "iv", when it is in page "v". Image attached for clarity

Any idea how to solve this??

```
% Table of contents
%\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

% Table of figures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

% Table of table
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

% Table of algorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\listofalgorithms

% Acronyms
\input{Auxiliar/03_Acronyms}

% Nomenclature
\textcolor{blue}{\input{Auxiliar/04_Nomenclature}}
```

[image]

Comment: Do `\usepackage{tocbibind}` and remove the `\addcontentsline` commands.

Comment: well the comment \cleardoublepage has a purpose. It prevents the \addcontentsline to be executed too early.

Comment: If you don't want the blank page from `\cleardoublepage`, then use `\clearpage`.  Otherwise, you're executing `\tableofcontents` on the previous page.  But it's probably easier to use `tocbibind` and have that take care of all the details.

Comment: @egreg thanks! Now sorted! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the ToC that you show there is content on page **iv** (the abstract). As such, issuing `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}` on that page will insert the **Contents** on that page in the ToC. It seems like you're using an `openany` style (since chapters occur on both odd and even pages), so update your code to the following:

```
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
```

This will ensure you or on a new page with nothing set before issuing the inclusion in the ToC and the `\tableofcontents` generation.